# Paypal express chekout blank order summary

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I got a problem on my paypal's order summary, nothing appears except total order:

[image]

here's my request (took from paypal's site, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/)

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=10% Decaf Kona Blend Coffee
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=623083
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Size: 8.8-oz
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=9.95
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=2
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=Coffee Filter bags
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1=623084
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1=Size: Two 24-piece boxes
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=39.70
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=2
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=99.30
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=2.58
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=3.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=2.99
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=-3.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT=1.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=105.87
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
&ALLOWNOTE=1
```

And the cmd express checkout call:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr
&cmd=_express-checkout
&token=EC%2d8KH91006BV366882T
&useraction=commit
```

Did i missed something?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Are you setting those parameters in both the DoExpressCheckout and SetExpressCheckout calls?

Comment: I don't do DoExpressCheckout because after SetExpressCheckout call (after cmd=_express-checkout call precisely) i'm redirected here.